# is it "safe" to expose your RxJS Subjects to the "outside world"

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I read this good article on 
[Angular onPush Change Detection Strategy](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4)

at some potin he wrote:

> It’s an anti-pattern to expose your subject to the outside world, always expose the observable, by using the asObservable() method.

but he doesn't explain why. Does this mean that I shouldn't do somthing like this?

```
export class ExampleComponent {

  public drawerTrigger$ = new Subject<{}>(); 
}
```

and in the HTML

```
  <button  class="hamburgher-button" type="button"
     (click)="drawerTrigger$.next($event)">
    <i >menu</i>
  </button>
```

if no, which is the proper way?

Comment: 1. Yes, that's what that means. 2. Already answered, in the quote: *"always expose the observable, by using the asObservable() method."*

Comment: Ok got it, but how? if I do somthing like 

`const test$ = this.drawerTrigger$.asObservable();`

I cannot call 

`test$.next($event)` 

in the HTML, and if i don't set drawerTrigger$ as  public I cannot use it in the HTML (The AoT compile fails)

Comment: So you have *two properties*, one private subject and one public observable. See e.g. this blog article I wrote: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't expose `Subject`s because this gives anyone using your service possibility to uncontrollably call `drawerTrigger$.next()` even in incorrect use-cases.

Even worst situations is that anyone can use `drawerTrigger$.error()` or `drawerTrigger$.complete()`. Subjects have internal state and if they emit `error` or `complete` the Subject is marked as stopped and will never ever emit anything. If you expose your `Subject` then you let anyone emit these notifications.

The officially recommended way of exposing Subjects from TypeScript classes is just forcing their types to `Observable`. You don't need to use `asObservable()` (RxJS itself doesn't internally use `asObservable()` anywhere in its codebase):

```
export class ExampleComponent {
  private drawerTriggerSubject = new Subject<{}>(); 
  public drawerTrigger$: Observable<{}> = this.drawerTriggerSubject;
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but in the HTML I should simply use a function that wraps the drawerTriggerSubject.next($event)?

Comment: You should better make the Subject private and then just create a method the emits the value `public onClick(e): void { drawerTrigger$.next(e); }` and then in the template call `onClick($event)`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what prevents one from doing `exampleComponent['drawerTriggerSubject'].next()` ?

Comment: @trichetriche nothing, you can do this as well as `(drawerTrigger$ as any).next()`

Comment: So as said in my answer, it's more of an intellisense convenience ? (and a "good practice" which you explained, even though it can be worked around)

Comment: If you use `as any` anywhere then you have a problem in your code because you're clearly doing this to avoid TypeScript types. The same reason is why `exampleComponent['drawerTriggerSubject']` is typically not allowed by tslint because there's no reason to use it unless you want to avoid TypeScript checks (if you need to use these then you don't need to be using TypeScript at all).

Comment: Not doing asObservable() exposes internal members of the subject. What you had wrote is not true, I don't know who officially recommends this. Types of TS can be easily avoided by casting back to Subject<T> thus it's not even a bit of protection.

Comment: @Azargoth You can't type cast `Observable` to `Subject`. Typescript's type checks won't let you do that. Only if you did something like this `(obs$ as any) as Subject` which is obviously very wrong. Fyi, https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2408#issuecomment-288845096

Comment: @martin That's ridiculous. Why TS  should limit type casting? I just run following code without any problems `const subject = new Subject<string>(); const trustMeImObservable: Observable<string> = subject; const notReally: Subject<string> = (trustMeImObservable as Subject<string>);`